# Comparison of Win32 CMutex and Standard Library std::mutex

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11, mutex, standard-library

Since the introduction of the `thread` library in C++11, I have been going through my code making some changes to move it away from platform specific multithreading code to portable standard library code.

However, I'm intrigued as to whether there is a performance or functionality difference between the standard library `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` and the Win32 specific `CMutex` and `CSingleLock`.

I've no experience with profiling multithreaded code and I don't know the internals of either of the two mutex classes so I wouldn't even be able to hazard a guess.

Comment: Just as a side note, `CMutex` and `CSingleLock` aren't from *Win32*, but from *MFC*, a third-party C++ library that wraps the *Win32* C-API. Though in practice there's probably a 1-to-1 match between a `CMutex` and the underlying Win32 mutex.

Comment: @ChristianRau MFC is not 3rd party: it's written by Microsoft.

Comment: @rubenvb Still it's nothing more than a wrapper around *Win32* and not related to it in any other way. It's just that the two parties having developed those two things worked for the same company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functionality deference is sure -- `CMutex` maps directly to Win32 mutex type while `std::mutex` is way more basic, likely implemented using win32 `CRITICAL_SECTION` removing the recursive  nature and `std::recursive_mutex` wrapping `CRITICAL_SECTION`. Those would work similar to `CCriticalSection`.

`CMutex` is a heavyweight that in practice is used to create named mutexes for interprocess communication. You should not use it intraprocess.

If your question stand comparing `recursive_mutex` vs `CCriticalSection`, I'd bet on practically same performance.  Interface-wise `CSingleLock` has completely braindead interface (it takes a second argument that defaults to `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`), so in practice I never used it directly only through macro to avoid mistake.

In new code I'd first try to solve things using `std::future`, and fiddle with locks only as last resort. The C++11 threading makes perfect sense to use, so until you need `CMultiLock` functionality it is better. I did not yet explore how to cover the latter case, but would be surprised if it can't be done easily.